# Table aliasing rules with nested join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this and it seems to be valid syntax:

```
SELECT
  A.email,
  A.handle as foo
FROM
  (
    user_table A
    INNER JOIN (
      klass_table K
      LEFT JOIN user_table B ON (B.x = A.y)
    )
  )
```

but if I re-use the alias (user_table A x2):

```
SELECT
  A.email,
  A.handle as foo
FROM
  (
    user_table A
    INNER JOIN (
      klass_table K
      LEFT JOIN user_table A ON (A.x = K.y)
    )
  )
```

then I will get this error:

> Not unique table/alias: 'A'

Can anyone explain the logic of how aliasing works in this case? If it's the same table, why does it need a different alias? Note these are nonsense queries - I am more concerned about the semantics/syntax rules here.

Comment: Each instance should have its own table alias! (More or less true, but good programming practice.)

Comment: *it seems to be valid syntax* it is not.

Comment: @forpas what is invalid about the first query? if you claim it's not, say what it is.

Comment: you might need a relation between the first and the second `user_table`s. This probability confuses the machine, since in that case both aliases are used synchronously.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
SELECT
  A.email,
  A.handle as foo
FROM
  (
    user_table A
    INNER JOIN (
      klass_table K
      LEFT JOIN user_table B ON (B.x = A.y)
    )
  )
```

selects 2 columns, but from which table or subquery? 
What is `A`? 
`A` is an alias for `user_table` but it exists only inside this subquery:

```
  (
    user_table A
    INNER JOIN (
      klass_table K
      LEFT JOIN user_table B ON (B.x = A.y)
    )
  )
```

Outside of this subquery it does not exist unless you alias this whole subquery like:

```
  (
    user_table A
    INNER JOIN (
      klass_table K
      LEFT JOIN user_table B ON (B.x = A.y)
    )
  ) A
```

Of course this `A` is not the same as the previous `A`.
The 1st `A` was an alias for the table `user_table` but 
the 2nd `A`is an alias for the subquery.

Comment: I would use `as A` to be clearer when aliasing otherwise people thing it's typo or something lol..but dunno if `as A` is a valid instead of just `A` there.

Comment: I agree that it is clearer for someone not used to sql syntax, but for someone more experienced `as` is just redundant coding.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.  If you want to re-use an alias, use a CTE:

```
WITH A as (
      SELECT *
      FROM user_table 
     )
SELECT A.email, A.handle as foo
FROM A INNER JOIN
     klass_table K
     ON . . . LEFT JOIN
     A A2
     ON A2.x = K.y
```

However, multiple references to the same table or CTE in the same `FROM` clause require different aliases.

Comment: what is a CTE? can you spell it out for newbs thanks

Comment: One thing that concerns me is if the inner alias can be seen outside the inner query or vice versa, if the outer alias can be seen within the inner query.

Comment: Common Table Expression, like a named subquery

Comment: Yeah seems annoying that you have rename it to A2 in order to reuse it? Why do we need the A2 variable? what's the logic?

Comment: A CTE is a bad suggestion. It *may* seem to lead to a clean syntax, but in Postgres, it will cause performance problems **if** the CTE is large, and its consumer(s) are more complex than`select * ...`